# Getting into a decent Ph.D. program with 3.3 GPA

Tags: phd, gpa

Long story short, I was caught up in the party life in my early 20's and my GPA was a 2.5 when I came back to school. Since returning to school I have done a 180 with straight A's for two of my last 3 semesters. From my current school, my GPA is a 3.5. I have yet to take the GRE but I know I will have strong letters of recommendations from professors and one offered to turn my research design for our final into an independent study with me the summer before I apply for Ph.D. programs. My question is will GPA reflect too poorly on me with a high GRE, strong letters of recommendation and research experience?

Comment: Your last three semesters have been 4.0's?  That's something to explain in a cover letter; happens all the time.